# Usage de la locution « ad infinitum »

Tags: usage, latin, locutions

Peut-on employer la locution adverbiale latine *ad infinitum* au lieu de *à l'infini* en français courant ?

Comment: Heuu... même moi... ne l'ai jamais entendue... alors... j'en doute... ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt En effet, je l'ai vue dans un livre anglais de la mécanique.

Comment: Je me permettrai de ne pas comprendre la raison du vote négatif sur cette question. Ce d'autant que la réponse apportée par @nonobstantfascisme m'a permis d'apprendre un truc : Sa possible communauté de sens avec *ad nauseam* qu'il m'est arrivé d'utiliser. Aussi me permets-je de dire merci aux deux intervenants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non**, on a toujours le choix mais couramment je ne crois pas en son utilité. On reconnaît peut-être davantage (mais ça ne veut pas dire grand chose) [*ad nauseam*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_nauseam#fr) ou [*ad vitam æternam*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_vitam_%C3%A6ternam), plus ou moins reliées. Il existe un très grand nombre de [locutions](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_locutions_latines) [latines](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Locutions_latines) provenant de diverses [sources](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_latine) (créées selon divers procédés). « Certaines expressions et locutions latines sont employées dans la langue générale » (BDL) mais *ad infinitum* n'apparaît pas dans au moins [une liste](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3799) qui les recense et cette liste contient peu de locutions employant la préposition latine *ad*. Le fait qu'une locution soit présente dans la langue générale ne signifie pas nécessairement qu'elle soit courante ou d'usage courant, semble-t-il. Dans certains cas on a une lexicalisation plus poussée où l'accentuation (par le truchement de la rectification orthographique par exemple) vient franciser le latin (ex. [*à priori*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3168) ; [contra](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/a_priori/4822/difficulte) ; mais la préposition *ad* ne correspond pas à une préposition française de même morphologie et accentuée, comme *à*) ; il y a parfois des hésitations avec l'emploi de l'italique (utilisé généralement pour les expressions étrangères) avec certaines locutions plus courantes.

Hormis quelques cas où c'est très lexicalisé, on pense que la majorité des gens ne sont pas familiers avec le latin au-delà d'y reconnaître certains étymons de mots connus, mais pas les cas que commandent les prépositions (comme l'accusatif avec [*ad*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad#Pr%C3%A9position_6)) et à mon avis cette méconnaissance de la préposition *ad* en particulier entrave le sens de la locution et diminue son utilité en français courant ; surtout qu'on a déjà l'adverbe *infiniment*, que le mot infini est très courant et qu'il ne s'agit d'un besoin de substantiver une locution par « dérivation impropre » etc. ; j'évalue ce genre d'emploi comme élitiste ou typique d'un jargon au style très archaïsant à l'écrit, alors qu'à l'oral il peut poser des défis supplémentaires de compréhension (de la prononciation, par exemple) pour l'interlocuteur.

Answer (score 2):

Ça n'est pas dans le TLFi mais c'est déjà [utilisé](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/ad%20infinitum/forced) en français.